# Java Arrays: Identify elements of a vector with constants

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have a String array (`String[]`) containing several String objects representing XPath queries. These queries are predetermined at design time. This array is passed to an object who executes the queries and then returns a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` with the results.

The map is made like this:

```
{Query that originated the result, Results vector}
```

Since I have to take these results and then perform some work with them, I need to know the individual queries. e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> firstQueryResults = xpathResults.getObject(modelQueries[0]);
... logic pertaining only to the first query results ...
```

Retrieving the results by an integer (in the case of the first query, "0") doesn't seem nice to me, so I was wondering if there would be the possibility to identify them via enum-like constants, for better clarity:

```
... = xpathResults.getObject(QueryDictionary.MODEL_PACKAGE);
... = xpathResults.getObject(QueryDictionary.COMPONENT_PACKAGE);
OR
... = xpathResults.getObject(ModelQueries.PACKAGE);
... = xpathResults.getObject(ComponentQueries.PACKAGE);
```

I thought of using maps (i.e. `Map<String, String>` as in `Map {ID, Query}`) but I have still to reference the queries via an hardcoded string (e.g. "Package").
I also thought of using `enums` but i have several query sets (Model, Component, ...) and I also need to get all the query in a set in a `String[]` form in order to pass them to the object who performs the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a marker interface:

```
public interface QueryType {
}
```

Then your enums can implement this interface:

```
public enum ModelQueries implements QueryType {
   ...
}

public enum ComponentQueries implements QueryType {
   ...
}
```

and so on.

Then your `getObject` method can accept a parameter of type `QueryType`. Were you looking for something like this? Let me know if I haven't understood your question properly.

Comment: I could use your strategy and then change the way a query is identified from a simple String to the Query type.
I would need to make the enums to hold a String attribute (to hold the query expression).

`public enum ModelQueries implements Query {
PACKAGE ("\\XPathQuery...");

String query;
ModelQueries(String query) { this.query = query; }
}`

Comment: Yep, that would be a way to do it. You could specify the method in the interface so that all implementing-enums would have to implement it.

Comment: Do you think that this kind of solution is overkill just to avoid "hardcoded" identification of queries (i.e. via integer - array index or via String - map key)? Or is it worth it for clarity?

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that the id didn't contain information about the query. I just looked at your edit to your comment. Having a separate enum per query might be overkill since it will lead to a type explosion as you need more and more queries.

Comment: However, you could still use the marker interfaces to identify groups of queries. So you could key your map as `Map<Query, ArrayList<String>>`, assuming you don't have an enum per query, but rather a bunch of queries per an enum (which represents a type of query, if I assume correctly).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have 4 Model queries and 5 Component queries for example. Since inheritance is not possible with enums I have some duplication of code for each set of query i made, but I think that now the code is more clear. Thanks!